# Should the “approve tag wiki edits” privilege be granted at fewer than 5,000 rep?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Seemingly, there are not enough users who have been granted the privilege (and are interested in exercising it) because I have had a tag wiki edit awaiting peer review for over 10 days.

Comment: Your feeling is likely to be correct - there aren't many active reviewers who look out for tag wiki/excerpt edits. I am one of them, and every time I go to review my decision, I mostly see the same peer reviewers' names on items. However, the relatively high threshold for the privilege is not the problem here - the sad fact is that review queues are a nearly soul-crashing experience. Part of that is the items themselves - heaps of very minor edits, looking out for plagiarism, manually checking replaced links, the list goes on. Another part is on SE - highlighting [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] doesn't work, guidance is lacking, there is little to no onboarding for new reviewers (what's worse, whatever bits we have at times contradict community guidelines), and on top of all that, tag wiki/excerpt edits are randomly spliced with all those "I fixed English in an unsalvageable post" items. Granted, the community has tools that fix many of those problems (Jammy - a bot that tracks tag wiki edits specifically, userscript that fixes highlighting, etc), but it all hinges on brittle third-party integrations that SE often breaks when they update something.

Comment: Personally, I _would_ like the ability to filter for suggested edits in queue instead of waiting for one to randomly pop up. As Oleg mentioned there's a slightly different skill set needed for reviewing tag wikis suggested edits and it would really help if I could just review a bunch of those in a row to get into a flow.

Comment: All the above quickly leads to burnout even for those few that can review tag wikis/excerpts in the first place. Add that we all have other projects and real life to worry about, and you'll get the gist of why it takes so long for an item to be reviewed. And, oh, don't forget that daily reviews are hard-capped to 40 (it's a bit more complex than that, but for SO it is essentially 40/day always), so even if we were to cap every day, there would still be a high chance of wait times. Then there is also an issue that a single person can't be an SME on everything, while the topicality of tags [3/4]

Comment: [4/4] varies greatly - so mindful reviewers tend to skip many review items, which also leads to delays. P.S. As a personal anecdote, my personal record is having to wait *1.5 months* (many editors have similar stories to tell).

Comment: I have had 5/5 tag wiki edits pending for over a month multiple times. I agree this is a problem but it doesn't seem to be a priority to anyone at the moment unfortunately

Answer (score 14):

Please don't make trivial changes to wikis. That's the sort of thing that clogs up the system. Your edit has now been rejected so you can move on.

Comment: Never mind wikis, don't make trivial changes in general. All those edits, to both wikis and posts, collectively clog up the system